# Git Should Not Checkin If Submodule Has Modified Files

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a built-in way (or a simple script) that won't let me check in if any of the submodules have modified files? As it stands now, I have useless commits, since I cannot return to the submodule's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to VonC for explaining what I needed to do. Sorry I don't know Bash, so here's the Ruby version. Works perfectly (in all cases so far, tested with git version 1.7.9.4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648585/git-should-not-checkin-if-submodule-has-modified-files
# October 1, 2012
# call this file pre-commit, make it executable and put it in .git/hooks
puts "Git pre-commit hook by Dan Rosenstark (yar)"
gitDiff = `git diff`
gitDiffWithSubmodules = `git diff --ignore-submodules`
if (gitDiff.length == gitDiffWithSubmodules.length)
  puts "Submodules are clean, going right ahead!"
else
  puts "One or more submodules are dirty, can't commit.'"
  exit 1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks like the pre-commit hook "[script for submodule hygiene](http://bloggoergosum.com/2008/08/19/pre-commit-script-for-submodule-hygiene/)" is for:
preventing the commit if a submodule has pending changes.
(See also that [patch/script](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-templates-make-example-pre-commit-hook-verify-submodule-commits-exist-td2785495.html))

That script was written 4 years ago, so maybe the git diff now includes a simpler way of detecting "dirty" submodules.

Comment: Thanks as always, I'll check it out. I hope I don't have to do any actual scripting :)

Comment: @Yar the script need to be declared as a pre-commit hook, meaning it will run on each commit, but will prevent the commit to actually occurs if it returns an error (like, here, if the submodule has uncommitted changes). See also https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils

Comment: Yeah, these are great, especially this one https://github.com/chaitanyagupta/gitutils/blob/master/submodule-hooks/pre-commit...  but this line `git diff --cached --name-only | grep -F mySubmodule` don't work

Comment: @Yar sorry, I meant for those links to provide an illustration of the principle you could apply in your case: a pre-commit hook with a simple `git diff` in it: the script would be much simpler and would (for instance, but you can implement it differently) compare the output of `git diff` and `git diff --ignore-submodules`: if different, that would mean one of the submodules is dirty, and the commit should not complete.

Comment: Okay my script is up as another answer. Seems to work just fine. Thanks for the help!!!